# <a (click)> in a string

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I have HTML content as string

```
var content = "some text <b>in bold</b>"
```

I output it well in

```
<div [innerHTML]="content"></div>
```

Avoiding HTML sanitizing I got it well bold as expected.

But I need to have more than bold: links

```
var content = "some <a (click)='aMethod()'>link</a> here"
```

Of course it doesn't work cause `(click)` is not compiled. I have a lot of content so I need to store this html in string. How could I do?

I cannot have my HTML code stored in components, I would have dozens of them, should I use `HostListeners`?

Comment: *I cannot have my HTML code stored in components, I would have dozens of them* dont use angular than. Besides, having dozen of components is quite normal for small applications :)

Comment: I'm not sure the problem you are trying to describe. If you need to bind to dozens of things, design the application around those things... whatever they might be. But I don't recommend whatever weird thing you are trying to do in Angular. You might as well drop the framework and use something... less robust.

Comment: Have you tried the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/innerhtml-click?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

.ts

`import { DomSanitizer } from "@angular/platform-browser";`

```
export class AppComponent {
  content: any;
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    Window["AppComponent"] = this;
    this.content = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml("some <a onClick='Window.AppComponent.aMethod()'>link</a> here");
  }


  aMethod() {
    alert("aMethod clicked");
  }

  ngDestroy(){
    delete  Window["AppComponent"];
  }
}
```

.html

```
<div [innerHTML]="content"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Adrita, you saved me !

Comment: You are welcome :) please upvote and accept the answer if it helped

Comment: Done !
Apparently it breaks the model dependency. In this aMethod(), if I set 
```
this.varTest=aaa
```
it's not reflected in the dom:
```
<div>{{varTest}}</div>
```
Here it displays nothing

Comment: @shawee Thanks for informing, I will look into this

Answer (score 0):

1. This will not work no matter what (in required form)
2. HTML in string will be escaped - it will be a "tekst" not a markup
3. To inject HTML in such form, you will have to disable sanitaizer
4. To make `(onClick)` work, it will have to be a plain javascript `onClick=javascript call` on `a` tag, as Angular's bindings are not done on strings